# Training program or training programme

Tags: word-usage

I hope that professionals would be able to answer the following question related to writing the word of 'program' / 'programme'.

As far as I know the first one is used in AmEN while the latter in BrEN. I believe that predominantly the American version is more popular. Can anyone explain me then, please, whether 'programme' is incorrect or outdated?

Thanks for your answers in advance.

Comment: As a Professional, I prefer words that do not have extra, silent letters in them. But that has been fought over for more than 100 years and nobody has "won" yet.

Comment: There are many words that are spelt differently between AmE & BrE, of which 'programme' (in the sense of list of events) is merely one example. That spelling is certainly not incorrect or outdated in BrE. We do, however, use the spelling 'program' when referring to a computer program. Hence you will actually see both spellings in BrE. Because of our usage of 'program' for 'computer program' and because of the prevalence of US literature, etc., I suspect that the AmE spelling is becoming more common even for non-computing usage.

Comment: Incidentally, you could probably have answered this question yourself just by looking in a dictionary - that's why someone has flagged your question for closure for lack of initial research!  See here [program](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/program) and [programme](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/programme).

Comment: @TrevorD Excellent comment, which you should probably make an answer. But I don't see any movement in Britain toward use of *program* for anything other than computer-related matters, or to organisational programs. Indeed I see it as a benefit to keep the separate spelling for things like Theatre Programmes, which are quite different things altogether.

Comment: @nocomprende all letters in all words are silent, in all languages. What are you even talking about.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Well, that is a modest proposal: just drop *all* the letters. Done! I am glad that this debate can finally be settled.

Comment: In British English the traditional spelling of 'programme' does allow us a useful distinction between "Theatre programme" or "Programme of work" and "Computer program" even though "Computer program" is derived ultimately from "Programme (or program) of instructions". Whether "Programme of instructions" should be "Program of instructions" probably depends on whether you credit Turing or von Neumann as being the father of the computer:-)

Answer (score 1):

Well as a native speaker of American English I would write *program*.  My colleagues from the UK, however, write *programme*.  Our policy at this university is to tell the students that either British or American English is acceptable as long as the student is consistent.

Having said that, the idea of one spelling being correct, really depends on the purpose of the text.  I just finished proofreading an article for publication in which the author had used American spelling exclusively.  The only problem was that the journal **specifically** stated the text must be in British English.  Thus, in this particular case, American spelling was considered *incorrect*.

Comment: Do you really mean "naive" in your opening sentence?

Comment: Good eye! Lol yes that is a typo. I meant native.

Comment: You can edit that ;)

Comment: I guess if he wrote naive instead of native, then he really is naive, so it should stand.

Comment: @user126158 Either way he's made a spelling mistake. If he meant to miss out the 't' he needed a diaeresis;-)

Answer (score 0):

The use of 'program' in UK may well be technically incorrect but it's useful to check on how other British writers feel about insisting on the 'amme' ending. One day I will probably feel too fuddy-duddy to insist on using it - and all the other different UK spellings. Using American language used to be regarded as showing off when I was growing up in the UK in the 70s. Now young people aren't aware of the differences.

"Are you done?"
"No, dear. I need another 10 minutes on gas mark 4."

I think it's good to have an additional source apart from dictionaries. This is an interesting question.

The other interesting point raised by this question is why we should have 'program/programme' after the word 'training' at all in the UK. If you need a word then why not say 'course' or 'scheme'?! Or just a 'talk', 'seminar' or 'webinar.'